# Why height is not 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, bho

I'm developing a BHO to deny access on prohibited URLs. So when I find some target URL, I just cancel navigation and open an iframe to another denied.html. But the height of this iframe for some reason isn't 100%. It appear in like 20% of the page. The code to create the iframe is:

```
  if pos('live.com', URL) > 0 then
    begin
      Cancel:= true;
      Document:= IE.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
      Document.body.innerHTML:= '';
      Document.body.style.height:= '100%';
      iFrame:= Document.createElement('iframe');
      iFrame.setAttribute('src', 'denied.html', 0);
      iFrame.setAttribute('position', 'absolute', 0);
      iFrame.style.height:= '100%';
      iFrame.style.width:= '100%';
      iFrame.style.left:= '0px';
      iFrame.style.top:= '0px';
      iFrame.style.border:= '0px';
      (Document.body as IHTMLDomNode).appendChild(iFrame as IHTMLDomNode);
    end;
```

I'm using live.com for testing purposes. and the line:

```
Document.body.style.height:= '100%';
```

is because I already read on internet that this problem maybe is because the html is not at 100% height, so I did it for test but continue not working. Someone have a solution for me??

Comment: SIDE NOTE: and if the site is foobarlive.com, would it still pass?

Comment: Still think you'd be better off with a redirect instead of a `iframe` overlay. The `iframe` is probably taking the height of the `body` and `html` elements; setting the `min-height: 100%;` might work, not sure with IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the html and body both to 100%

```
html, body { height : 100% }
```

Comment: I was thinking this would require `min-height: 100%`, but I could be wrong. Not sure if all "supportable" versions of IE support that property either.

Comment: How to do this with IHTMLDocument2?? Can you help?